# Datatable Getchanges not working

Tags: ado.net, datagridview, datatable

I have a datatable which is bound to a DataGridView in my C# winforms app.

I want to pass datatable to the server side with only those rows which are changed/updated by the user in the datagrid.

But dataTable.GetChanges() is returning me all the rows instead of just the changed ones.

Am I missing something over here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use **GetChanges()** on **DataTable**, not **DataSet**.

```
DataTable dtChanges = ds.Tables["DataTable"].GetChanges();

if ( dtChanges != null)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtChanges.Rows)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Changes: " + dr["DataStr"]);
    }
}
```