# Null DataSet when using SqlDataAdapter.Update method

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

I'm attempting to update values in a database by editing them in a dataGridView (Windows Form). However, when calling SqlDataAdapter.Update() in the code below, it's saying that my DataSet is null. I've searched online and found that adding AcceptChanges() after GetChanges() has worked for most people, but this has not fixed my error.

Below is the code which I am trying to use, any help is appreciated.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        carHireDataSetBindingSource.EndEdit();

        string connectionString = "Data Source=SQLServer;Initial Catalog=CarHire;Integrated Security=True";
        string selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM CarHire.dbo.Customer";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();

        DataSet ds = carHireDataSet.GetChanges();
        carHireDataSet.AcceptChanges();
        DataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString);
        da.Update(ds);

        con.Close();
    }
```

EDIT: Tried this, still same error.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        carHireDataSetBindingSource.EndEdit();

        string connectionString = "Data Source=SQLServer;Initial Catalog=CarHire;Integrated Security=True";
        string selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM CarHire.dbo.Customer";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();

        DataTable dt = carHireDataSet.Tables["Customer"].GetChanges();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        ds.AcceptChanges();
        DataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString);
        da.Update(ds);

        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650218/datatable-getchanges-not-working

Comment: Post code how you you are binding datasource to datagridview.

Comment: @Sujith I updated my code in my post but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you debugged and seen what is there is "ds" ??? if it is null then this line "DataSet ds = carHireDataSet.GetChanges();"  has an issue

Comment: Yes, ds is null. That is what this question was asked for.

Comment: @MIdrees I have bound the datasource to the gridview from the properties window.

Comment: use this to see whether your source dataset really has changes "dataSet.HasChanges(DataRowState.Modified | 
        DataRowState.Added)&& dataSet.HasErrors"  .. more on this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4ey25we(v=vs.110).aspx  .. if that expression returns false, your dataset is not having any changes

Comment: the expression returned false, but I am manually changing a value in the gridview.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact exception message, and an indication of the row that throws it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it better to execute an update when the user finishes editing a row.

Move your code from `CellEndEdit` event to `RowValidated` event.

```
private void dataGridView1_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //Here place your code to update
}
```

Comment: I have moved my code to the RowValidated event, however this has not fixed my issue. Thank you for your input though.